How to Filter Data Directly in Solana Rust Program Before Fetching in Node.js?
is it possible to filter data directly within my Solana Rust program before fetching it in Node.js? Currently, I fetch all data and filter it in JavaScript, but I'd like to perform filtering on-chain, such as filtering by date, directly within the Rust code. This way, I could call a Rust function from my JavaScript to fetch only the filtered data. Is this feasible, and if so, how might I implement this in Solana Rust?

There might be a misunderstanding about what on-chain programs are for. They're typically for manipulating on-chain state, and not for examining transactions executing on the chain. If you want to filter the output from something like logsSubscribe https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/logssubscribe, you'll need to do it all client-side, or run a validator with a Geyser plugin which filters the data https://docs.solanalabs.com/validator/geyser
